# Syntax error on an SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm facing this problem

```
08-23 14:54:25.370: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16728): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT latitude, longitude FROM table
```

when the compiler tries to execute this query:

```
String[] result_columns = new String[] {COL_LATI, COL_LONGI};
       Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, result_columns,null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

What can be the source of the problem? I'm not seeing any syntax error on that query. No?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is your table called table? That could very likely be confusing SQLite.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler:No, it's "coord".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error comes from the fact the reserved keyword `table` is used after the `from` clause of the SQL query. But in the comments you said that the table is called `"coord"`, not `"table"`.

Check your `static final String TABLE_COORD`, I think it is erroneously set to `"table"` instead of being set to `"coord"`.

Comment: AAAAA how i did not noticed this error? And when did i change it ! Sometimes we're making some weird things. Thank you for helping.